# Text carousel transition

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have built a text carousel but I don't know how to add transition/animation effects to it. I would want to have the effect apply anytime the innerText changes.

```
<div class="carousel">
  <p id="test-msg"></p>
  <p id="test-name"></p>
</div>
```

```
.carousel{
  transition: ????? 3s ease-in-out;
{
```

```
const msg = document.getElementById('test-msg'),
  person = document.getElementById('test-name');

const data = [
  {message:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti animi sapiente corporis aut suscipit esse nam repellat, molestiae consequatur voluptas pariatur', name:"Yaw Boakye - CEO, ABC International"},
  {message:'odio excepturi aliquid, quaerat consequuntur culpa libero harum illum tempore. Mollitia eos praesentium recusandae consectetur temporibus incidunt voluptate', name:"Kwadjo Mensah Bukari - Intrepreneur"},
  {message:'id quis asperiores magni eum dolores ullam ipsa, vitae voluptatum quas. Repudiandae, perferendis provident. Laudantium, beatae recusandae placeat suscipit', name:"Cecelia Marfo - Supervisor, Google"},
  {message:'ea animi. Doloribus eveniet est vero perferendis, sapiente provident debitis, facilis dolorum natus laboriosam alias ex eaque rem veniam fugit quam. Reiciendis', name:"Yakubu Mohammed - Business Man"},
  {message:'quas quidem molestias libero fugit iste voluptates magnam neque vero a vel, numquam blanditiis optio recusandae corrupti repellendus temporibus itaque!', name:"Yaa Doris - Trader"}
];

let counter = 0;

function setMsg(data){
  let {name,message} = data[counter];

  msg.innerText = message;
  person.innerText = name;
  counter++;
  if(counter >= data.length){
    counter = 0;
  }
}

setMsg(data)

setInterval(function(){
  setMsg(data)
  console.log(counter)
}, 10000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this trick without transaction I've to use animations, but we need to make sure the time of the frame and the time in setTimeout, the time for animation must match the time in the setInterval function

just you need to change your css file to be like :

```
.carousel{
  overflow: hidden;
}

.msg {
        transition: all 0.3s; 
      animation: slid 5s infinite;

    }

    @keyframes slid {
        0% {
            transform: translateX(50%);
        }
        20% {
            transform: translateX(0);
        }
        80% {
            transform: translateX(0);
        }
        90% {
            transform: translateX(0);
        }
        95% {
            transform: translateX(0);
        }
        100% {
            transform: translateX(-50%);
        }
    }
```

and the time here

```
setInterval(function(){
  setMsg(data)
}, 5000)
```

Answer (score 2):

Does it work your you?

```js
const msg = document.getElementById('test-msg'),
  person = document.getElementById('test-name'),
  carousel = document.getElementById('carousel');

const data = [
  {message:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti animi sapiente corporis aut suscipit esse nam repellat, molestiae consequatur voluptas pariatur', name:"Yaw Boakye - CEO, ABC International"},
  {message:'odio excepturi aliquid, quaerat consequuntur culpa libero harum illum tempore. Mollitia eos praesentium recusandae consectetur temporibus incidunt voluptate', name:"Kwadjo Mensah Bukari - Intrepreneur"},
  {message:'id quis asperiores magni eum dolores ullam ipsa, vitae voluptatum quas. Repudiandae, perferendis provident. Laudantium, beatae recusandae placeat suscipit', name:"Cecelia Marfo - Supervisor, Google"},
  {message:'ea animi. Doloribus eveniet est vero perferendis, sapiente provident debitis, facilis dolorum natus laboriosam alias ex eaque rem veniam fugit quam. Reiciendis', name:"Yakubu Mohammed - Business Man"},
  {message:'quas quidem molestias libero fugit iste voluptates magnam neque vero a vel, numquam blanditiis optio recusandae corrupti repellendus temporibus itaque!', name:"Yaa Doris - Trader"}
];

let counter = 0;

function setMsg(data){
  let {name,message} = data[counter];

  carousel.style.opacity = "0";
  counter++;
  setTimeout(function(){
    msg.innerText = message;
    person.innerText = name;
    carousel.style.opacity = "1";
  }, 1000);
  if(counter >= data.length){
    counter = 0;
  }
}

setMsg(data)

setInterval(function(){
  setMsg(data)
  console.log(counter)
}, 10000)
```

```css
.carousel{
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
{
```

```html
<div id="carousel" class="carousel">
  <p id="test-msg"></p>
  <p id="test-name"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: It works but the effects only happens at the end. I want to have it both at the beginning and the end.

Comment: I think it happens both. I made transition duration 1 sec to make the effect more obvious